# Disney+ just got installed without my permission

Tags: permissions, windows-11, windows-store

I'm running Windows 11 Pro 21H2. This morning I noticed that I had two notifications as shown on the bottom right corner of the screen. I opened it and saw two messages. One said Disney+ was just installed, the other Spotify Music just got installed.

I didn't request them to be installed. Can Microsoft Store install apps without my permission? How do I prevent it from doing so?

Comment: You probably use a Microsoft Live account. Does anyone else also use this account? If they install it on another computer, it gets installed on all devices.

Comment: @LPChip I use a local account. I don't even use a Microsoft account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, [Windows can "push" applications onto your PC](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/stop-windows-10-installing-unwanted-apps). The PC manufacturer can also install possibly unwanted apps, termed bloatware, such as trial versions of an antivirus.

There are a few things you can do to prevent that, such as turning off suggestions, installing a privacy application to prevent updates and turning off push services (although they can also be installed via Windows Update, which you should *not* turn off, so you can get security updates).

- Right-click the desktop, select *Personalize*, and *Start* settings. Turn off *Show suggestions...*, which tries to push more apps.
- In the *Microsoft Store* application, turn off *Update apps automatically*.
- In *Regedit*, at `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\ContentDeliveryManager`, create a DWORD, `SilentInstalledAppsEnabled`, and set it to 0 (zero).
- Use a third-party application that turns off many of these settings that intrude on privacy and disregard your control, such as [O&O's free ShutUp10 utility](https://www.oo-software.com/en/shutup10) or one of [the many alternatives](https://alternativeto.net/software/shutup10/). *Caveat:* before installing *any* software, check its reputation and safety online, such as with [VirusTotal](https://www.virustotal.com/gui/home/upload).
- If junk has already been installed, remove it with [Bulk Crap Uninstaller](https://www.bcuninstaller.com/), [O&O AppBuster](https://www.ghacks.net/2021/12/19/remove-pre-installed-windows-11-apps-with-oo-appbuster/) or any [alternative](https://alternativeto.net/software/bulk-crap-uninstaller/), with the same *caveat*.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. (1) I didn't see the "Show suggestions..." option. I only have "show recently added apps", "show most used apps", "show recently opened item in Start, Jump lists, and File Explorer", plus "Folders". (2) I never sign in Microsoft Store and it still can push apps to my PC? Talking about intrusion.

Comment: Actually, "Spotify is included as part of the UWP app "bloatware" of Windows," according to MS: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/how-to-stop-microsoft-store-from-installing/b9e8fd4f-1808-4f3f-b817-bec2de26e363 . Again, use a third-party tool to turn off some of these obnoxious intrusions, such as ShutUp10 -- you'll be surprised how many other services are gratuitously installed. Or use another operating system, e.g., Linux, which does *not* install unwanted packages.